# Apple simd: outer product of two vectors

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, simd, accelerate-framework

Doesn't Apple simd module have a standard function for [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors? I see it only has `dot_product` and `cross_product` for vectors.

Using matrix representation of vectors for implementing outer product via matrix multiplication doesn't seem possible also since Apple simd doesn't support 1-dimensional matricies afaik.

So the only way is to implement outer product themself? Not that it's hard, I just find it amusing that specialized vector library doesn't have outer product as a standard function.

I use this implementation for now:

```swift
func outer_product(_ a: float2, _ b: float2) -> simd_float2x2 {
   simd_float2x2(a*b.x, a*b.y)
}
```

Comment: If I read the wikipedia page correctly, isn't the outer product just the same as "point-wise multiplication"? That is, every cell in the output matrix is just the multiplication of the same positioned elements from the two input matrices. Is that right?

Comment: @Alexander, no. Outer product of two vectors does form a matrix and it supports multiplication of vectors of different sizes. It's not much harder to implement then "point-wise multiplication", but it's not the same.